# is online resize2fs ext4 close/reset all open files?

Tags: linux, ext4

On my `CentOS 6.x` I did online `ext4` filesystem resize using `resize2fs`.

The only program running on this disk was sphinx search.

I noticed that sphinx server had lots of:

```
[Sun May  1 11:11:11.479 2011] [21134] WARNING: send() failed: 32: Broken pipe
```

One possible explanation is the open files were closed.

Is online resize2fs ext4 close/reset all open files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing an ext4 filesystem won't affect any open files.

Anyway, your error message is about `send()`, which isn't used for regular files. It's used to write to sockets, such as network connections or UNIX domain sockets.

You should also look at the timestamp...

Comment: that was second thing what I am thinking. probably fs were read only or "not even read only" for a while and those were incoming connections. timestamps are fake. will accept the answer soon.